# What is the difference between module and distribution on CPAN?

Tags: perl, cpan

I was just comparing the numbers if different "Archive Networks", like CPAN, CTAN, rubygems.org etc. CPAN displays two very different numbers:

- 105,774 modules
- 24,657 distributions

As I'm not a Perl programmer (I'm just preparing a talk for university), I'm not familiar with Perl's wording. I tried to look them up and only found "module" to be defined by Perl itself. As far as I understood it, a module is any file with a namespace.

However, I can't find any declarations of what a distribution is. Even CPAN only shows a list of modules or they use both words together (as "module distribution"). Can anyone clear my mind?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A distribution will contain one or more modules, documentation, a build script, and also typically a test suite, a file manifest, readme, change log, and license information. Modules bundled together in a distribution are often part of complete class library, or at the very least all related tools divided into intuitively-named packages.

Taking, for example, the core [IO](https://metacpan.org/release/IO) distribution, you can see it contains the following modules:

- IO - load various IO modules
- IO::Dir - supply object methods for directory handles
- IO::File - supply object methods for filehandles
- IO::Handle - supply object methods for I/O handles
- IO::Pipe - supply object methods for pipes
- IO::Poll - Object interface to system poll call
- IO::Seekable - supply seek based methods for I/O objects
- IO::Select - OO interface to the select system call
- IO::Socket - Object interface to socket communications
- IO::Socket::INET - Object interface for AF_INET domain sockets
- IO::Socket::UNIX - Object interface for AF_UNIX domain sockets

Comment: You download and build a distribution from CPAN, which will install one or more modules.

Comment: Thanks Richard. So to compare archive networks I should use the number of distributions, since they come close to the meaning of gems (Ruby) or packages (Python, Haskell, …) - right? And just to confirm this fact: Did I get the notion of a module right (a file with a namespace, e.g. the file behind IO::Dir)?

Comment: I don't see how you can compare and get any sort of meaningful number. You can't count distributions (e.g. all of the modules in IO could have had their own distribution) and you can't count modules (e.g. a date-time library could store all time zone info in one module, or could store each time zone in a different module). And then there's the question of how many modules are used, usable, redundant, etc.

Comment: @ikegami I think I can compare them, since all archive networks suffer the same problem. I just need to know which meaning comes close to the meaning of 'package' most languages use. As an example, "activerecord" is a single gem on rubygems.org, even though it comes with a massive suite of files and capabilities. On the other hand there are many gems to connect "activerecord" to various databases, e.g. "activerecord-jdbc-adapter". So the problems are the same everywhere, therefore I can compare these numbers if digested with a bucket of salt.

Comment: @Florian Pilz, Suffering from the same problem doesn't make them comparable, because they the problem could make the number 10x larger on one network and 10x smaller on another network. So unless you consider 10,000 equal to 100, the numbers are meaningless without a *lot* of extra analysis

Comment: @ikegami Like I said, it's just a talk in a class at the university I'm attending. I think a short slide with a comparison of archive networks is nice, even if it doesn't get a lot of information across. However, I'm still not sure if a module means the same as a file (with a namespace). I would prefer to get an answer on that, than to discuss if the numbers are comparable (which they are not, but I will do it anyway).

Comment: @Florian Pilz, There's no official definition of a module. The de facto standard is probably "a file with a namespace declaration", which is pretty much "a `.pm` file" since there is usually a 1:1 link between `.pm` files and namespaces. By namespace, I mean `Foo::Bar`, as distinct from `Foo::Baz` and `Foo::Bar::Baz`.

Comment: @Florian Pilz, In Perl, one usually loads a module with a compile-time version of `require Some::Module;`, which is equivalent to `require "Some/Module.pm";`.